# sum of $9$ consecutive natural numbers and $10$ consecutive natural numbers are equal

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find the smallest natural number which can be expressed as sum of $9$
> consecutive natural numbers and also $10$ consecutive natural numbers.

I considered these sequences of natural numbers: $x+1,\cdots,x+9\quad\text{and}\quad y+1,y+2,\cdots,y+10\quad$ therfore :

$$9x+45=10y+55=a\quad\text{where}\quad x,y,a\in\mathbb{N}$$

But I don't know how to find minimum of $a$.

Comment: Can you solve $9x+45=10y+55$?

Comment: The answer depends upon whether you consider $0$ a natural number.

Comment: When did we start considering 0 a natural number? I thought(and was taught) that it will be counted with whole numbers.

Comment: It is better to use $\Bbb Z^+$ instead of $\Bbb N$ because many people understand $0$ to belong to $\Bbb N$.

Comment: Hey @philomath, did you add x with those? It starts with x+1.

Comment: Hey @lee I started the sequences with $x+1$ and $y+1$ so that I can add them up easier (use formula $S_n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$).

Comment: But what about x and y aren't those numbers? I got 9x+36 and 10y +45

Comment: @lee $x$ and $y$ are natural numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let those numbers be $$x+1,x+2,...,x+9$$ and $$y,y+1,...,y+9$$ Then, $$a = 9x + 45 = 10y + 45 \\ 9x = 10y \implies x = \frac{10y}9$$
Since $\gcd(9,10)=1$, it follows that $9$ divides $y$. Minimum such natural $y$ is $9$. Hence $$a=10\cdot 9 + 45 = 135$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $9x+45 = 9(x+5)$ is a multiple of $9$ at least as large as $54$, and $10y + 55 = 5(2y+11)$ is a multiple of $5$ but not $10$ (why?) and at least as large as $55$.

The smallest number fitting both these criteria must be the multiple of $9$ ending with $5$. Since $9$ and $5$ are co-prime, these are just odd multiples of $45$ (so they don't end with a $0$). Then we just have $45 \times 3 = 135$ as the smallest number fitting the criteria.

Indeed, $135 = 11 + 12 + ... +18+19$ and $135 = 9+10+... + 17+18$.

Comment: At the first line I think $9x+45$ is at least $45$ because $x$ can be $0$.

Comment: @philomath It is a matter of convention, whether $0$ can be a natural number or not. If it can, you are right since $45$ is just $1+2+...+9$ and then $0+1+2+...+9$, otherwise $135$ is correct. The answer $45$ is too obvious because adding $0$ changes nothing, so I think $0$ is meant to be excluded and $135$ is right.

Answer (score 1):

$9x=10y+10\implies y+1\equiv0\mod 9$ so $y=9k-1,k\in\Bbb Z^+$. The smallest such $y$ is $9-1=8$ for which we get $x=10$ and $a=135$.

Note that if we take $0\in\Bbb N$, then the smallest permissible $y$ is $9(0)-1=-1$ for which we get $x=0$ and $a=45$.

Answer (score 1):

I guess we’re not including zero as a natural number here or the answer would be very simple (45).

So the sum of a sequence of consecutive natural numbers is average times count. We know the count and the average will be an integer for odd-length sequences and half more than an integer for even length sequences - we can bring that back to an integer by doubling the average to an odd number and halving the count, but the result for a 10-length sequence will be odd

Thus we know that our answer is divisible by $9$ and by $5$. Discarding $45$ the next is $90$, which is not odd so we move on to $135$. This implies that the average is $15$ for the length-9 sequence and $13.5$ for the length-10. So
$$ 11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19 = 8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17 =135$$